# jquery: arrow up/down keys in input tag change selected <select> item

Tags: jquery

I know there are hundreds of similar questions out there, and believe me when I
say I've read a lot of them, but still the problem remains. If I have an input
tag id="input1" and a select id="list1", I want the up/down arrow keys when
pressed in the input component to move the selected option in the select list
up or down accordingly.

I've set the value of the select tag so that the first item in the options list
is selected, but this code doesn't work. I've checked that the bind for the
keydown event is working ok, and I've tried setting focus temporarily to the
select before triggering a keyup/keydown/keypress (all tried) event on the
select component. Should I perhaps be focusing on the select component and then
triggering a select or change event before triggering the keypress event?

```
        deflectEvent = function(event) {
            if((event.which == $.ui.keyCode.UP) ||
              (event.which == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN)) {
                //$('#list1').focus(); //.focus().click();
                $('#list1').trigger(event);
                //$('#input1').focus();
                return false;
            };
        }
        jQuery(function($){$('#input1').bind('keydown',deflectEvent)});
```

What I observe happening, is errrm, nothing. On IE8 I can press an arrow key and get the 
focus to shift using $('#list1').focus().focus().click(); but on chrome I can't even do 
this.

I'm aware of the jquery simulate plugin, although I've not managed to track
down any examples of it's use. For example, if you simulate a keypress event,
how do you specify which key was pressed?

Thanks.

Comment: I apologize if answer below is not what you looking for but i was little confused as to what exactly you wanted.

Comment: No worries, thanks for going to the trouble of replying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you were after?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
deflectEvent = function(event) {
    var noOfListItems = $("#list1 > option").length-1;
    var curListItem = $("#list1")[0].selectedIndex;
    if(event.which == $.ui.keyCode.UP) {
         // Decrement the selection by one, unless that will be less than zero, then go to the last option
        var nextListitem = (curListItem-1 < 0) ? noOfListItems : curListItem-1;
        $("#list1")[0].selectedIndex = nextListitem;
    }
    if(event.which == $.ui.keyCode.DOWN){
         // Increment the selection by one, unless that will be more than the number of options, then go to the first option
        var nextListitem = (curListItem+1 > noOfListItems) ? 0 : curListItem+1;
        $("#list1")[0].selectedIndex = nextListitem;
    }
}

jQuery(function($){$('#input1').bind('keydown',deflectEvent)});
});
```

[jsFiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/Toukakoukan/aB5F9/21/)

Comment: You bet it was what I was looking for, and thanks for going to the trouble of making this word perfect to plugin to my code, it works perfectly. Reading this makes me realise that there's something I need to read. Whilst I can understand what the code above in a general sense, could you point me in the direction of any documentation that will describe the properties and events associated with the various tags? I am just learning. Thanks, you're a goddamn superstar.

Comment: No trouble at all!  
The only really unusual properties in this code are selectedIndex and .length as used as a property of a selector.  selectedIndex is simply the number associated with the currently selected option (starting at 0, so option 1 has the index 0 and option 2 has the index 1). length as a property of a jquery selector simply returns the number of elements that the selector matches (in this case, the number of options in our select box), as this starts counting at 1, we have to decrement it by 1 to match the index. The only event  is the same keydown event you had in your code :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's working example, http://jsfiddle.net/FEnnA/ I tested it in IE 8.0 FF 3.5, 4, 5, 6 and Chrome (idk the version for Chrome).

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
```

CSS:

```
input{
    display:block;
}
```

JS:

```
$('input').keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
       $(this).prev().focus();   
    }    
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
       $(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```